# If $Z$ is Hausdorff and if $Z=M\oplus N$, then $M$ and $N$ are closed.

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

Let $Z$ be a topological vector space over a field $K$.

> If $Z$ is Hausdorff and if $Z=M\oplus N$, then $M$ and $N$ are closed.

**Defn:**

$X$ is said to be topological vector space if

$(i)$
 $X$ is a vector space and the addition and scalar multiplications defined are continous.

$(ii)$ $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space.

Give me a hint to proceed with the proof...

Answer (score 2):

The canonical projection $M\oplus N\to M$ is continuous and as $0\in M$ is closed ($M$ is Hausdorff, too), its preimage $N$ is closed.

Comment: how $0\in M$ gives $M$ is closed?? May you explain?

Comment: Please provide details..

Comment: He does not claim $M$ is closed. He claims $0$ is closed in the subspace topology of $M\subset Z$. This is true because $M$ is Hausdorff. Once you have this, you use that preimages of closed sets under continous maps are closed (by definition)

Comment: canonical projection need normal group know.  Here $M$ will be a normal group of $M\oplus N$? I am asiking by referring this link http://planetmath.org/canonicalprojection